# Proof or disproof that $\frac{\pi^{8}}{3150}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{3} e^{-4(k + 1)t}}{1-e^{-4(k + 1)t}}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I need a proof or disproof of- $$\frac{\pi^{8}}{3150}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{3} e^{-4(k + 1)t}}{1-e^{-4(k + 1)t}}\,dt$$

Comment: I don't think your integral is written correctly; shouldn't the exponents depend on $t$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $\alpha\gt0$,
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3\mathrm e^{-\alpha t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha t}}\mathrm dt=\frac1{\alpha^4}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3 \mathrm e^{-t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}\mathrm dt.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3 \mathrm e^{-t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}\mathrm dt=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\int^{\infty}_{0}t^3 \mathrm e^{-nt}\mathrm dt=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^4}\int^{\infty}_{0}t^3 \mathrm e^{-t}\mathrm dt.
$$
Since
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}t^3 \mathrm e^{-t}\mathrm dt=\Gamma(4)=6,
$$
all this implies
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3 \mathrm e^{-4(k+1)t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-4(k+1)t}}\mathrm dt=\frac1{4^4}\cdot\left(\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^4}\right)^2\cdot6.
$$

Comment: Thats a very good disproof but can you prove - $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3\mathrm e^{-\alpha t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha t}}\mathrm dt=\frac1{\alpha^4}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^3 \mathrm e^{-t}}{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}\mathrm dt.$

Comment: Yes I can (otherwise I would not state it).

Comment: please do it by editing your answer.

Comment: Try the change of variable $t\to\alpha t$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\sum_{n \geq 1}{1 \over n^{4}} = {\pi^{4} \over 90}}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin We know that. And?